# How to transfer data from 1 MongoDB collection to multiple tables in PostgreSQL using Azure Data Factory

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, azure-data-factory, etl, data-transfer

I have an use case of transferring the data from MongoDB to PostgreSQL.
I can able to transfer from single collection to single table using copy activity, but I need to transfer the data from single collection to multiple tables in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

***To transfer data from 1 MongoDB collection to multiple tables in PostgreSQL using Azure Data Factory you need to first get the tables name through lookup activity and the then through foreach loop load it in multiple tables in PostgreSQL.***

---

**You can follow the below steps:**

- In your pipeline take a Lookup activity and get the list of table name and schema name where you want to load data.
  [image]
  you can see table name and schema name in in above preview data.
- Now drag the foreach loop activity, then connect it with the Lookup activity. Click on Foreach loop activity, then go to the settings tab and then click on Add dynamic content and here pass output of Lookup activity with expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
  [image]
- Inside the Foreach loop activity, take a copy data activity, add your mongodb database as a source.
  [image]
- In a sink dataset create parameters for table name and schema name
  [image]
- Add that parameter in connection of sink [image]
- Add the foreach items as dataset parameters as `@item().table_name`, `@item().table_schema`
  [image]

And the run the pipeline it will load the data of single collection to multiple tables.

**Pipeline Executed Successfully:**

[image]